# How can I find a GPS unit that can display north at the top at all times?

Tags: gps

When cycling, and increasingly when hiking, I use a bike computer GPS app on my phone, but my phone is no longer waterproof, so I'm thinking of a dedicated GPS device.  However I'm picky, and having borrowed a couple of devices haven't found one I like.  I find that I have a much better sense of direction if I follow a breadcrumb trail with the map set to north at the top, rather than turning with the road.  Combined with good mapping on a good screen (easily identified) this makes things like rerouting and working out what I can see in the distance much easier.  This is probably a legacy of learning to navigate on paper, which in many ways I still prefer for hiking - but I want to navigate, not be navigated.

But this feature either doesn't exist on any unit, or is never listed in the specs - so how can I identify a device that supports it, before ordering (and I would have to order online)?

Comment: [Garmin](https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/gpsmap64/EN-US/GUID-A2942AF4-B8E1-4790-9CE2-F8058FD39719.html) seems to have this option.

Comment: @WeatherVane you mean the Garmin GPSmap64 does, I assume.  The several other Garmin devices I've tested or asked the owners about don't.  The GPSmap64 has some nice features (and some that I'm less keen on).  It's interesting that while I've only seen "north top" they use "north up".  If that's universal it may be helpful for brands that put full manuals online in a searchable way - it suggests that some Garmins for cars do this - no use to me but indicative

Comment: ...Maybe also some recent etrex

Comment: FWIW I found it by first searching "tomtom always north" and then "garmin always north".

Comment: @WeatherVane I'd tried a few combinations, though I hadn't thought of tomtom.  I was mostly using quotes in my search because of lots of nonsense hits otherwise, and apparently  not quite the right term

Comment: Why don't you buy a new phone?

Comment: @WeatherVane I might do that as well.  The one I have is rugged but so big and heavy it breaks handlebar mounts or isn't secure in them, so it's come off at >30km/h several times and that's why it started leaking.  After that gave me navigation trouble (and last year's crash)  I do want a backup device that communicates, so if I could get a GPS that was good enough for my primary navigation, my phone could be the backup

Comment: My Garmin Oregon can do what you want. You can also get dedicated mounting clips that it can slide / click onto. Maps can be from OSM so basically free.I like a dedicated GPS receiver because battery life is much better (basically I can use it for a full day without having to switch batteries).

Comment: @PaulPalmpje I'm starting to wonder if the answer is simpler than I thought - basically I need to RTFM on devices that otherwise do what I want.  I happen to have tested several that don't support it.  I have the opposite problem with batteries.  An Etrex gives 16 hours on a set of AAs, and some of my rides are longer than that with a lot of screen use.  I can keep my phone topped up using my dynamo or a USB pack but I would have to change batteries during a ride.

Comment: Every GPS device I have ever owned has north at top either as default or as an option: various Garmins, eTreks and TomToms, as well as all my android phones

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'm thinking of deleting the question.  It appears that the current models that don't do it are all bike-specific, and the general purpose models that don't are ancient (like the one I have here), also some rather dumb android apps that I would have rejected anyway.  Most of the ones I've been able to check have been cycling models.

Comment: @ChrisH I would recommend you self-answer your question, with what you learned from the various comments and your own research. Specifically, that many models of GPS support north-at-the-top as an option, and maybe list some of the models/manufacturers you found that do and don't support that option. I think that could be very useful information to someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many even most current models do in fact support this.  It's presumably common enough that the manufacturers don't feel the need to specify.  Manuals and menus aren't always clear, and experienced owners have told me that it's not an option on their device when it actually is buried somewhere.

Garmin use the term "north up" (as opposed to "track up") and their manuals are searchable online.  For some models the setting is a feature of an activity profile rather than global.  While my original Etrex lacks this option, most more recent models do.

For Wahoo, disabling "always rotate map" via the android app is the way to configure it, but this only applies if you're not following a route.

In both cases it's a configuration option rather than something easy to toggle from the navigation display. The few modern devices that really don't seem to offer this option are those that that provide only minimal mapping features on the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

The point of having a GPS displaying a map is to know where you are instantly by looking at it, which can't be done if the map rotates. So most GPS'es will have the feature you want, and since it's quite an obvious feature, it won't be listed in the specs.

Simply google "name of your GPS" and "north up", for example "garmin north up". You'll get the [manual page](https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/edge520/EN-US/GUID-31DFA9B0-ED18-4F14-86C6-9060F24B198A.html) explaining how to set it up.

If you want a cycling GPS then the other features you might consider interesting are compass, altitude sensor, and other bicycle interfaces like heart rate monitor or cadence sensor.

Without an onboard magnetic sensor (compass) the GPS has to guess your heading from the direction of your movement on the map, which requires a good enough GPS signal, and it only works when you are moving. In other words, if you're moving slowly or are stopped deep in the woods with bad signal, a real compass works a lot better whether it is inside the GPS or just a good old compass on your handlebar. Also the latter doesn't require batteries and will get you home even if the GPS dies.

The altitude sensor measures elevation more accurately than the GPS does. GPS is pretty accurate for positioning but it requires more visible satellites and good signal for accurate altitude.

And make sure the screen is readable in full sunlight, and the touchscreen still works in rain.

Answer (score -2):

In most GPS navigator is such a function. But if you are not sure about it, you can look to characteristics or ask some people that have already bought it. I have this function in my omTom Go Comfort 6 and switches on in settings and names "show the north".

Comment: That's a driving TomTom, not an outdoors one, so isn't relevant.  And the reason I asked is that the feature I wanted isn't listed in the specifications, so I can't "look to characteristics".  Some have enough detail in a  manual online, but then I have to find the manual for every plausible model.